# Term for conditional entropy conditioned on a specific value?

Tags: terminology, information-theory

The conditional entropy of $Y$ given $X$ equals

$$H(Y|X)=\sum_{x}p(x)\cdot\sum_y p(y|x)\cdot\log\left(\frac 1 {p(y|x)}\right)$$

Which can be written as

$$H(Y|X)=\sum_{x}p(x)\cdot H(Y|X=x)$$

**Is there a term for $H(Y|X=x)$?**

Comment: I think not. This is the simplest form for entropy of an r.v. given another r.v..

Comment: What you wrote in the title: "entropy conditioned on a specific value"